# detecting the dialog result from an out of process dialog box

Tags: c#

I have developed a tool in .net using c# that will aid in checking in and out particular types of files using Team Foundation Server. There is a point in time though that my tool really needs to know what the dialog result is from when a user responds to a message dialog box that pops up once TFS or "Team Foundation Server"  is done doing a merge. Basically I need my tool to sit either in a loop or timer and wait for this response, but I'm unsure how to accomplish this. I've googled it, but no one it seems has had a need to do this.

Comment: If you are still looking for a solution I may have one. However, to provide you with the best solution, I'd like to know if the out of process result is on the same machine, or over a network.

Comment: I would definitely love to see what that solution would be. I'm actually not looking any longer, but I'm interested. To answer your question, the out of process result is on the same machine.

thanks, dan

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/), you can write script that will wait for a window (using [WinWait](http://www.autoitscript.com/wiki/WinWait)) and then do something according.

Comment: i appreciate the feedback. Its not what i am looking for, but I appreciate the effort.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [SetWindowsHookEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644990%28VS.85%29.aspx) to install a hook function to listen for events in the other process.  Note that this would install the hook function in every process running in your system and must be written in an unmanned (C/C++) DLL.

But with this you could use the [WH_CBT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644977%28VS.85%29.aspx) hook to and the [WH_MSGFILTER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644987%28VS.85%29.aspx) hook to listen for the button clicks on the dialog.

This is somewhat dangerous as you will be injecting a DLL into each process running under the current user, that is the code that you write in your DLL will be loaded and executed in each process.  You'll also need to worry about inter-process communication since your hook code will be running in the TFS process, although you may get by with named [mutexes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682411%28VS.85%29.aspx) since you just need a simple notification.